# Can a Riemannian submanifold effectively act as a local tangent space?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, general-relativity

I have been studying rudimentary gauge gravity, using the soldering equation to show how local P-translations can be related to global Lorentz and coordinate transformations. My question relates to the tangent space $T_{p}M$ at a point $p$ on a manifold $M$, and the properties of hypersurfaces (submanifolds) of $M$, which I'll denote $X$. Essentially, if $X$ and $M$ share a point $p$, then is the the exponential map $exp:T_{p}M\rightarrow{M}$ equivalent to $exp:T_{p}X\rightarrow{X}$?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. To begin with, a sphere does not have boundary. It is possible that what you mean (from the "intuitive description") is two different round $n$-dimensional spheres in $R^{n+1}$ which are tangent to each other at a single point. Mathematicians distinguish *spheres* and *balls* (the latter do have boundary). But then the rest of your question makes no sense. (What is "congruent", what tangent space?) My suggestion is to read a differential geometry textbook not written by a physicist.

Comment: In general, a Riemannian manifold has nonzero curvature, hence, is not locally isometric to a Euclidean space (e.g. its tangent space at a point) which might be what you are asking about.

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent"? These are very different maps. Unless $X$ is totally geodesic, its exponential map at $p$ is not the restriction of the exponential map of $M$. And your last paragraph is so cryptic, I cannot even guess what it means.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I mean that the exponential map that maps a vector from $T_{p}M$ to a point $p$ on $M$ performs the same function as the exponential map from $T_{p}X$ to a point $p$ on $X$, since both $X$ and $M$ share the point $p$.

Comment: This makes even less sense. What do you mean by **a** point $p$? This point is fixed in advance. Do you know what the words "restriction of a map" mean in math?

Comment: I mean any point that the submanifold and the manifold have in common, since $X$ is contained in $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to ask: Suppose that $M$ is a Riemannian manifold, $X\subset M$ is a hypersurface equipped with the Riemannian metric induced from $M$. Fix a point $p\in X$. We then have two exponential maps: $\exp_p^M: T_pM\to M$ and $\exp_p^X: T_pX\to X$. (A caveat: The metrics might be incomplete and the exponential maps might be defined only on neighborhoods of $0$ in the respective tangent spaces. I will ignore this issue.) We have the natural inclusion $T_pX\subset T_pM$. Then your question  is:

> Is it true that $\exp_p^X$ equals the restriction of $\exp_p^M$ to $T_pM$?

Since you do not seem to know what the word "restriction" means, here is a reformulation of the above question:

> Is it true that for every vector $v\in T_pM$ (where both $\exp_p^M$ and $\exp_p^X$ are defined) we have $\exp_p^X(v)=\exp_p^M(v)$?

The answer to this question is in general negative. The reason is the failure of $X$ to be **totally geodesic** in $M$. (A submanifold $X$ of a Riemannian manifold $M$ is called totally geodesic if each geodesic in $X$, with respect to the metric of $X$, is also a geodesic in $M$.) As a concrete example, consider $M={\mathbb R}^n$ with the standard flat Riemannian metric (with the metric tensor $g_{ij}(x)=\delta_{ij}$). Let $X\subset M$ be a round sphere. Then for each point $p\in X$, $v\in T_pX$, $\exp^M_p(v)\ne \exp_p^X(v)$, unless $v=0$.

---

Addendum: Much of the trouble that physicists have with explaining themselves to mathematicians comes down to the matter of language, since mathematics is **both** *science* and *language*. Here is a fragment taken from Richard Feynman's book "Surely you are joking, Mr. Feynman." There, Feynman explains that he had invented alternatives to the standard math notation and what was the result:

> I thought my symbols were just as good, if not better, than the regular symbols - it doesn't make any difference what symbols you use - but I discovered later that it does make a difference. Once when I was explaining something to another kid in high school, without thinking I started to make these symbols, and he said, "What the hell are those?" I realized then that if I'm going to talk to anybody else, I'll have to use the standard symbols, so I eventually gave up my own symbols.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I was looking for, thank you. I am teaching myself, so apologies for not using correct terminology.